# @ Binding override default value?

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS component that's used on multiple pages. In that component I have these bindings:

```
cancelText: '@',
confirmText: '@',
```

And this class:

```
@Inject('$mdDialog')
export class MultiLinePromptDialogComponent {

    public cancelText = 'Annuleren';
    public confirmText = 'Bevestigen';

    constructor (private $mdDialog) { }

    public cancel(): void {
        this.$mdDialog.cancel();
    }

    public confirm(): void {
        this.$mdDialog.hide(this.result);
    }
}
```

In other components I create a template with this component:

```
template: `<multiline-prompt-dialog cancel-Text="Cancel">
```

When I open the dialog in the browser I can see the `Cancel` text which is expected. But when I define the component in the template like so:

```
template: `<multiline-prompt-dialog">
```

Without the `cancel-Text="Cancel` attribute and I check the component in the browser the template shows nothing. While I would expect it to show the `public cancelText = 'Annuleren` value. But it looks like the binding is overriding that value with a empty string.

We just upgrade to Angular 1.7 so the issue might be from that upgrade.

Comment: is it possible to see the controller part of your component?

Answer (score 1):

```
//Try add this code in your component controller to initialize the empty or not valued variables
app.directive('multiLinePromptDialog', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        cancelText: '@',
        confirmText: '@'
    },
    controller: ['$scope',function($scope){
        if($scope.cancelText == null || !$scope.cancelText.replace(/\s/g, '').length)
            $scope.cancelText = 'Annuleren';
        if($scope.confirmText == null || !$scope.confirmText.replace(/\s/g, '').length)
            $scope.confirmText = 'Bevestigen';
    }],
    template: 'html code',
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the solution was making the binding optional :)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a change in AngularJS binding. You can now add `?` to your binding to make it optional.

```
cancelText: '@?',
confirmText: '@?',
```

This way if the binding is undefined it's not used so the component refers to the default values giving in the class.